# Doctrine 2 does not recognize SELECT on the FROM clause

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I have a SQL query I would like to use in Doctrine2.

My query, goes to the dabatase, does a `GROUP BY` user state and `COUNT` the number of users per state.

Then I'm trying to join a table to `COUNT` all users and make a percent for every state.

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery("
                SELECT COUNT(u.id) as total, 
                    (100*(COUNT( u.id ) /  total_users.total)) as percent
                FROM UserBundle:User u,
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) as total
                     FROM UserBundle:User) as total_users
                LEFT JOIN u.idUserEstado ue
                GROUP BY u.idUserEstado")
            ->getResult();
```

The problem is, when I run the Doctrine2 query I get an exception:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 397 near 
'(SELECT COUNT(': Error: Class '(' is not defined.
```

Doctrine does not recognize that `SELECT` on the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Select on the from clause are not handled by doctrine 2

There is a closed (and not accepted) feature request on doctrine's jira : http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2793

> DQL is about querying objects. Supporting subselects in the FROM
>   clause means that the DQL parser is not able to build the result set
>   mapping anymore (as the fields returned by the subquery may not match
>   the object anymore). This is why it cannot be supported (supporting it
>   only for the case you run the query without the hydration is a no-go
>   IMO as it would mean that the query parsing needs to be dependant of
>   the execution mode).

Answer (score 1):

```
(SELECT COUNT( * ) as total FROM UserBundle:User) as total_users
```

`COUNT(*)` may not exists in DQL. Try `COUNT(u.id)`, the results will be the same. You also have the possibility to try this in an EntityRepository :

```
$qb->select(array(
    'count(u.id) as total',
    '(100*(count(u.id)/total_users.total)) as percent',
    'select count(u.id) as total_users) as total_users'))
   ->from('UserBundle:User')
   ->leftJoin('u.idUserEstado','ue')
   ->groupBy('u.idUserEstado');

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Source: [Google UserGroup issue](http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/43fa9880949f2bd7?pli=1)

Comment: Yes, that was another error i had, thanks for reporting :), i already corrected, but problem persists.

Comment: I just edited my answer, maybe you should try with the querybuilder into your UserRepository

Answer (score 0):

the

```
...  FROM UserBundle:User u, ...
```

is strange. Maybe it can't find the class User.

Comment: What he seems to be not recognizing is the all the (SELECT COUNT( * ) as total FROM UserBundle:User) as total_users inside the FROM