# Joining table with min(amount) does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, min

I have 3 tables, but data is only fetch from 2 tables.

I'm trying to get the lowest bids for selected items and display user name with the lowest bid.

Currently query works until when we display user name, it shows wrong user name, which does not match the bid.

Below is working example of structure and query.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31a288/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE `bid` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` float NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `bid` (`id`, `amount`, `user_id`, `item_id`) VALUES
(1, 9, 1, 1),
(2, 5, 2, 1),
(3, 4, 3, 1),
(4, 3, 4, 1),
(5, 4, 2, 2),
(6, 22, 5, 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `item` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'chair'),
(2, 'sofa'),
(3, 'table'),
(4, 'box');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'James'),
(2, 'Don'),
(3, 'Hipes'),
(4, 'Sam'),
(5, 'Zakam');


ALTER TABLE `bid`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `item`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `user`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `bid`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

ALTER TABLE `item`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

ALTER TABLE `user`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT b.id, b.item_id, MIN(b.amount) as amount, b.user_id, p.name
FROM  bid b
LEFT JOIN user p ON p.id = b.user_id
WHERE b.item_id in (1, 2)
GROUP BY b.item_id
ORDER BY b.amount, b.item_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31a288/1/0)**:

```
| id | item_id | amount | user_id |  name |
|----|---------|--------|---------|-------|
|  5 |       2 |      4 |       2 |   Don |
|  1 |       1 |      3 |       1 | James |
```

Explanation of query:

- Get the selected items (1, 2).
- get the lowest bid for thous items - MIN(b.amount)
- display user names, who has given the bid - LEFT JOIN user p on p.id = b.user_id (**this is not working or I'm doing something wrong**)

[Note] I can't use sub-query, I'm doing this in doctrine2 (php code) which limits mysql sub-query

Comment: Please add all relevant info into the question. Links break - especially SQLFiddle

Comment: Add the desired results

Comment: @Basit Is that query running. Surely it is erroring telling you that the other columns need to be added to the group by?

Comment: @CathalMF: Then you are running your MySQL in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not necessarily fetching the user_id who has given the bid. You group by item_id, so you get one result row per item. So you are aggregating and for every column you say what value you want to see for that item. E.g.:

- MIN(b.amount) - the minimum amount of the item's records
- MAX(b.amount) - the maximum amount of the item's records
- AVG(b.amount) - the avarage amount of the item's records
- b.amount      - one of the amounts of the item's records arbitrarily chosen (as there are many amounts and you don't specify which you want to see, the DBMS simply choses one of them)

This said, b.user_id isn't necessarily the user who made the lowest bid, but just one random user of the users who made a bid.

Instead find the minimum bids and join again with your bid table to access the realted records:

```
select bid.id, bid.item_id, bid.amount, user.id as user_id, user.name
from bid
join 
(
  select item_id, min(amount) as amount
  from bid
  group by item_id
) as min_bid on min_bid.item_id = bid.item_id and min_bid.amount = bid.amount
join user on user.id = bid.user_id
order by bid.amount, bid.item_id;
```

Comment: you got a typo, `select` should fetch user's ID as `user.id as user_id`

Comment: @ThorstenKettner how can I do this without sub-query? doctrine limit us from using sub-query.

Comment: I am pretty sure that MySQL doesn't feature any SQL elements to write this query without a subquery - at least not with the database as is. If you are allowed to make additions to the database, however, you can create a view for the subquery and then join that view instead of the subquery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27872702/75799 - as you can see, I can't use sub-query inside from clause, is there any other alternatives?

Comment: As I said: create a view.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, just question. isn't it create view is just for temporary. I mean if someone bid after view is created, then it wont have the changes inside the view unless we delete it and recreate it. right? or m I wrong in this?

Comment: You are wrong. With a view you simply define the query that is to be executed everytime you select from the view.

Comment: By the way: You can even make the *whole* query a view and then simply `select * from the_view` in Doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a subquery. I am not 100% sure if this is the most efficient way, but at least it works.

```
SELECT b1.id, b1.item_id, b1.amount, b1.user_id, p.name
FROM  bid b1
LEFT JOIN user p ON p.id = b1.user_id
WHERE b1.id = (
   SELECT b2.id
   FROM bid b2
   WHERE b2.item_id IN (1, 2)
   ORDER BY b2.amount LIMIT 1
)
```

This first selects for the lowest bid with for item 1 or 2 and then uses the id of that bid to find the information you need.

**Edit**

You are saying that Doctrine does not support subqueries. I have not used Doctrine a lot, but something like this should work:

```
$subQueryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$subQuery = $subQueryBuilder
    ->select('b2.id')
    ->from('bid', 'b2')
    ->where('b2.item_id IN (:items)')
    ->orderBy('b2.amount')
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->getDql();

$queryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $queryBuilder
    ->select('b1.id', 'b1.item_id', 'b1.amount', 'b1.user_id', 'p.name')
    ->from('bid', 'b1')
    ->leftJoin('user', 'p', 'with', 'p.id = b1.user_id')
    ->where('b1.id = (' . $subQuery . ')')
    ->setParameter('items', [1, 2])
    ->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

Comment: I can't use sub-queries :(

Comment: Why not? Looking at the tags that belong to your question it looks like you are using MySQL, which does support subqueries.

Comment: Oh I see, you are using Doctrine. Then I would suggest two separate queries. Will probably not hurt performance that much. However, it seems that Doctrine can actually handle subqueries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762586/how-to-convert-this-to-doctrine-2-querybuilder-format/10763358#10763358 However, I am not a Doctrine expert.

Comment: I tried some things out and added a working Doctrine implementation to my answer.

Comment: I have tried your normal query with sqlfindle, it does not give the desired result as it gives for below answer. but I kinda wish your query did give that result, because you have doctrine example too, which I can work with. his `join(..)` is not possible i think, but I'm trying to find out.

Comment: There was something wrong with the query indeed (duplicate aliases), I updated my answer. I think the query now works as expected.

Comment: well, no the result is not accurate. it should display both items result, but its showing only one item

Comment: Ah okay, I did not understand your question right then. You might be able to convert Thorsten's answer to Doctrine, but it is probably much easier to just run a few queries instead of trying to do it all in one. Or just use raw SQL instead...

Comment: I have manage to do it in nativeQuery and then remapping the query to entity, that would give proper objects, rather then arrays and keeping it as one query. But thanks for your  help tho